# Delete a point in scatter plot after elapsed time - matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

How can I delete the first point added to a plot after a certain time has elapsed?

```
p= np.random.random()
q= np.random.random()
plt.scatter(p,q)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not provide much details, but I hope this short example helps:

```py
import time
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# create dummy data
n = 50
p, q = np.random.random((2, n))

dt = 0.1  # time interval after which one point should be removed [seconde]

h = plt.plot(p, q, ls='', marker='o')[0]

i = 0
t0 = time.time()
while i < n:
    t = time.time()
    i = int((t - t0) // dt)
    h.set_data(p[i:], q[i:])
    plt.pause(dt*0.8)  # pause the plot a little less than dt
```

[image: 50 Fading Points]